# Get area from Sentinel-2 with Python

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I'm using an array [n,m,4] (4 bands) download from Sentinel2 but the data doesn't have the parameters like transform, spatial_resolution, etc. Can I convert the array and parameters to GeoTIFF or GDAL data and get the shapefile and area of my AOI?

```
evalscript_bands = """
    function setup() {
        return {
            input: [{
                bands: ["dataMask","B02", "B03", "B04", "B05", "B08", "B12"],
                units: "DN"
            }],
            output: [{
                bands: 6,
                sampleType: "INT16"
            }
            ],
        };
    }

    function updateOutputMetadata(scenes, inputMetadata, outputMetadata) {
        outputMetadata.userData = { "norm_factor":  inputMetadata.normalizationFactor }
        outputMetadata.userData = {"inputMetadata": inputMetadata }
    }

    function evaluatePixel(sample) {
        return [sample.B02, sample.B03,sample.B04,sample.B05,sample.B08,sample.B12];
    }
"""

def get_all_data(time_interval):
    return SentinelHubRequest(
        evalscript=evalscript_bands,
        input_data=[
            SentinelHubRequest.input_data(
                data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL2_L2A.define_from(
                name="s2", service_url="https://sh.dataspace.copernicus.eu"
            ),
                time_interval=time_interval,
                mosaicking_order=MosaickingOrder.LEAST_CC,
            )
        ],
        responses=[SentinelHubRequest.output_response("default", MimeType.TIFF),],
        bbox=aoi_bbox,
        size=aoi_size,
        config=config,
    )

slots=[('2024-01-17','2024-01-19'),('2024-01-24','2024-01-26')]

list_of_requests = [get_all_data(slot) for slot in slots]
list_DATA = [request.get_data()[0] for request in list_of_requests]
```

So, I got the data from two diferents dates but no the geospacial information. I used the next code to get that information.

```
 client = Client.open("https://earth-search.aws.element84.com/v1")
collection = "sentinel-1-grd"
tas_bbox = [-74.2294, 4.6627015, -74.18812, 4.7040215]
search = client.search(collections=[collection],
                       bbox=tas_bbox,
                       datetime="2020-01")

items = list(search.items())
print(f"Found: {len(items):d} datasets")
stac_json =search.item_collection_as_dict()
```

And I get the properties like epsg, bbox, shape, transform, etc. I want to use those properties to convert my array *list_DATA* to GeoTIFF and create the shapefile to know the AOI area.